# Closed differential form on cone

Tags: real-analysis, differential-forms

I'm not sure how to proof this theorem.

Let $w=\sum_{i=1}^{n}f_idx_i$ on C conic set. If $f_i$ is homogeneus (p-degree) and $w$ is closed.

$\Rightarrow$ $w$ is exact and $$g=\frac{1}{p+1}\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_if_i$$ is a primitive.

I have thought about using Euler's theorem about Homogeneus function but I'm stuck.

Euler's Theorem:

*f on conic set is homogeneus p degree $\Leftrightarrow$ pf(x)=$\nabla f(x)\cdot  x$*

My thoughts:

$$ (p+1)\frac{\partial}{\partial k}g(x)=f_k(x)+\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i\frac{\partial}{\partial k}f_i=(p+1)f_k(x) $$

So
$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial k}g(x)=f_k(x) $$
So, for each k, I found a potential $\nabla g$ which is equal to $\vec{f}$ and so $w$ is exact.

Is it correct?

Comment: Please define $g$.

Comment: Also, should $i+1$ be $i=1$ in the lower summation limit for $h$?

Comment: Sorry, typing errors.

Comment: I think you mean to say "... and $g = \ldots$ is a primitive". Saying "... and $g = \ldots$ where $g$ is a primitive" makes it sound like you're asserting *every* primitive satisfies that equation, which is patently false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a standard way to get a primitive on a star-shaped region by doing the line integral along rays from the star-point (in this case, the origin). In particular, doing the line integral along the line segment from the origin to $x$, we will have 
\begin{align*} 
g(x) = \int_0^x \omega &= \int_0^1 \sum f_i(tx)x_i\,dt  = \int_0^1 \sum t^p f_i(x)x_i\,dt = \sum x_if_i(x) \int_0^1 t^p\,dt \\ & = \frac1{p+1}\sum x_if_i(x), \end{align*} 
as you desired.
You can check that $dg = \omega$ because $\omega$ was closed to start with.

P.S. I don't think that Euler's Theorem on homogeneous functions is relevant.